# String conversion to DATETIME in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to convert a string to `datetime`. I need to store `datetime` with milliseconds in SQL Server 2005.

example:

```
SELECT CAST('2010-07-28 20:07:25.733000000' AS DATETIME)
```

when I try I am getting error like

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Comment: In addition to the current answers, it's worth noting that if you are going to continue to convert to `datetime` rather than `datetime2`, you ought to replace the space between the date and time with the letter `T`. E.g. `'2010-07-28T20:07:25.733'` - otherwise, the conversion may fail if different language settings are in force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to truncate.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(23), '2010-07-28 20:07:25.733000000'));
```

Comment: but i need store complete value.i mean '2010-07-28 20:07:25.733000000'

Comment: ...and as @Damien_The_Unbeliever points out, you'll want to be sure that your language and dateformat settings are appropriate, or just pass in `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.mmm` in the first place.

Comment: Then you are using the wrong data type. If you are using SQL Server 2008, you should use `datetime2`. If not, then there is no way to store that in SQL Server 2005 or lower using a native datetime type. You could store it as a string but I don't recommend that. If these are always trailing zeros, why do you need to store them? You can always add them at presentation time.

Comment: @BhaskaravarmaDandu - A `datetime` in SQL Server 2005 can only store 3 digits of millisecond information (and the final digit is further restricted), so what you're asking for cannot be accomplished.

Comment: could you please help me with similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63037209/datetime-conversion-from-mongodb-string-to-sql

Answer (score 2):

(With rounding) the milisecond range is 0-999 in a `DATETIME`, for more precision use `DATETIME2` if your using SQL2K8.

Comment: truncate to ensure you don't provide > 3 decimal places as in Aaron's answer, or do you mean store more millisecond precision?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the last 0:s in the miliseconds this will work:

```
SELECT CAST('2010-07-28 20:07:25:733' AS DATETIME)
```